# How do I get an object's texture as a png

Tags: texturing

I'm really bad at Blender. I'm only using it because Roblox Studio is incapable of transfering textures from a model to a mesh.

I saw someone ask this already and someone answered that you would have to go to UV Editing and export it from there.

But for some reason instead of the whole thing's texture, it just shows a weird purple texture.

[image]

Comment: That's the normal map (for the sword handle) by the look of it. The filename at the top of the UV window (MeshPart1_nmap.png) confirms that. Hover over the R/H 3D window and press 'A' to select All and see what appears in the UV window. You haven't said what are you actually trying to do BTW?

Comment: Im gonna need to make a new post but I'll reply to this one first
-
because for some reason nothing shows up in uv editing anymore
-
but ill still explain what i wanna do. so basically i made this sword in roblox studio but when you turn a model into a mesh the texture kind of doesnt transfer over so im just trying to download the swords texture as a png because roblox accepts png as textures
-
hopefully that made sense